# How to query "pending my approval" items in IBM WCM 7.0

Tags: content-management-system, wcm

I'm working in a project which reques me to display a list of "pending my approval" my items to content manager of my client. I've checked the new Query API inside WCM 7. I'm thinking I need following code to query the content libraries:

```
    QueryService queryService = workspace.getQueryService();
    Query query= queryService.createQuery(Content.class);
    query.addSelector(Selectors.libraryEquals(library));
    // Following selector is faked
    query.addSelector(Selectors.waitingMyApproval());
```

The last line in above script is a faked one, which doesn't exist in WCM API. com.ibm.wcm.workplace.wcm.api.WorkSpace has an "hasManagerAccess(DocumentId) boolean" method, but it can only check one document.

Is there a way to query the whole library and get all items pending on approval of current user?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer from IBM forum (provided by David De Vos) and document it here:

> Try using the WorkflowSelectors.approversContains() selector which
>   expects you to supply one or more strings representing the
>   distinguished names of the approvers to look for.